# Django - Grouping users in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create user groups like `Programmers` , `Designers`, `Managers`.. I am not talking about groups based on permissions. I.e,

I am creating a new `News` object from django admin. And there is a `target_group` field in `News` model.

I want to add some users to this news object. And if i select `Programmers` from creation form, it should add all users i added to `Programmers` group. This must be like a `Many2ManyField`. But instead of selecting users, i want to select groups which contains a list of some users.

I think default `Groups` tab in django admin doesn't provide something like this.

Any tip or help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# models.py
class News(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

# forms.py
class NewsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(News, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.group is not None:
            # here self.instance.group is need you group (programmers, managers etc.)
            users_queryset = User.objects.filter(groups=self.instance.group) 
            self.filelds['users'].choices = [(u.id, u.username) for u in users_queryset)

# admin.py
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsAdminForm
```

Comment: dont try yet. but it looks like fine. thanks.